# Does absorbed energy from sun go to increasing atmosphere's height, as well as heating earth up?

Tags: meteorology, climate

Water transports heat from the surface of the earth to the upper atmosphere by evaporation, which cools the surface, and then condensing at cloud height, where it releases latent heat. So water decreases the temperature gradient, and in the process expands the atmosphere so that it reaches a greater height. I am wondering if this takes a significant amount of energy to raise the atmosphere to greater heights, and if so does that take away from some of the energy that goes to global warming?

Comment: Gasses do expand however the density of atmospheric gasses is denotes little thermal absorption. Ci2, methane and water vapor are the biggest greenhouse gasses and have infrared expulsion profiles to re emit thermal energy.